# What is roughly equivalent to aka?

Tags: vocabulario, coloquialismos

I'm after something concise and somewhat common in usage. Would "también llamado" work, or is there something better?

Comment: [*Alias...*](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/aka) or [*también conocido como...*](http://www.spanishdict.com/examples/aka) are common ways to express this in Spanish. https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=aka

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At least in Argentina: *alias*, *también conocido como*, *comúnmente nombrado* and *comúnmente conocido como* are pretty similar.

For example, "Dwayne Johnson, **aka** The Rock" could be *"Dwayne Johnson, **alias** La Roca"*.

***Alias*** is concise and probably your best choice:

> **[alias](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=alias)**
>
> Del lat. *alias* 'de otro modo'.
>
> 2. adv. Por otro nombre. *Alfonso Tostado, alias el Abulense.*

Comment: "Alias" is a standard word, used all over the spectrum of dialects and, in particular, in Castilian Spanish. Certainly the best fit.